# Cuál es la version de php_pthreads.dll necesaria en php 7.0.20?

Tags: hilos

Use las versiones desde la php_pthreads-3.1.0-7.0-ts-vc14-x86 hasta la php_pthreads-3.1.5-7.0-ts-vc14-x64 y apesar que el Apache reinicia perfectamente, cuando trato de hacer una operación multithread me genera el siguiente error:

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll' - No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.
 in Unknown on line 0

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Notice: Use of undefined constant PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE - assumed 'PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE'

Comment: intentastes registrar la dll a ver si no hay ningun problema, o tiene problemas de dependencia?? regsvr32

Comment: Ahora puse php_pthreads.dll en c:\xampp\php\ext y pthreadVC2.dll en c:\xampp\php y ejecuto el Apache y me genera el siguiente error:  "Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method."

Comment: ejecutalo como administrador